# Dependency injection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Coming for a JavaScript and Java background, I find dependency injection in Laravel (or PHP) extremely confusing.

For example (Laravel 5.1), in Middleware/Authenticate the constructor takes a Guard object. I have search the codebase and the class Authenticate is never instantiated.

So where is the Guard coming from then?

Thanks, SK.

Comment: Much of Laravels work in done using reflection: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php and php's magic methods: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php. You won't necessarily find objects being directly instantiated.

Comment: @craig_h thanks, useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the laravel documentation:

Dependency injection is a fancy phrase that essentially means this: class dependencies are "injected" into the class via the constructor or, in some cases, "setter" methods.
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container

You can instantiate Guard in your code or fetch instance of Guard from somewere and pass it to Middleware/Authenticate constructor.

EDITED : 
Guard is injected into the Middleware/Authenticate automatically somewere in laravel framework code at some point. You better take a look on different example of Dependency injection in Laravel where all is visibly in your code.

Comment: Yes I have read that and I have used 'dependency injection' in JavaScript. 
My question is how Guard is injected into the Middleware/Authenticate automatically.

Comment: Where is being DI in Laravel, I mean creation of instance class of injectable object?

Answer (score 0):

Defn : Dependency injection is a technique whereby one object supplies the dependencies of another object.

You could visit the link below for a detailed explanation with ioc container explanation
Visit : https://www.thelearninguy.com/dependency-injection-in-laravel-using-ioc-container